# Understanding Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, ado.net-entity-data-model

I Googled to find tutorials and documentation on Entity Framework and read a couple of articles too. I referred to MSDN documentation also, but still I am not able to understand it clearly.

With a little that I followed is that:

(1) Each table along with rows are considered as a single unit.

(2) It provides a solution to sudden table name change without affecting the application.

(3) It reduces a lot of code.

Can someone explain me in a more easy way with illustrations? Please don't be too technical.

Comment: Check out http://www.ef-faq.org/ - it is a new site just created by Danny Simmons with lots of links to EF resources...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out:

- [Entity Framework Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399567.aspx)
- [Intro to Entity Framework with SQL Server](http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1963)
- [Beginner's Guide to Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ee712907.aspx) (has lots of articles, videos, etc.)

It's rather hard to find something that's not too technical and just shows nice graphical representations.

But basically you have three "layers" inside an EF model:

- the **physical** database model - what tables and columns do you have?
- the **conceptual** model - the business objects / entities you want to work with (which can be very similar or quite different from your physical model)
- the mapping layer that defines the mappings between those two worlds